# how do i transform a data array into another format?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a `const reserved: Date[]` which looks like this:

```
0: Thu Oct 01 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale) {}
1: Sat Oct 10 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale) {}
2: Fri Oct 30 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale) {}
3: Sat Oct 31 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale) {}
4: Fri Oct 02 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale) {}
```

but I would like this array to present itself to me like this:

```
0: 2020/10/01
1: 2020/10/10
2: 2020/10/30
3: 2020/10/31
4: 2020/10/02
```

I try to transform the date through this way:

```
     for (const element of reservedArray) {
        this.shareDate.newdate = this.shareDate.pipe.transform(element, 'yyyy/MM/dd');
        this.shareDate.arraydateRes.push(new Date(this.shareDate.newdate));
        console.log(this.shareDate.arraydateRes);
    }
    }
```

the result of the console.log is this:

```
(10) [Thu Oct 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale), Sat Oct 10 2020 00:00:00
 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale), Fri Oct 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa
 centrale), Sat Oct 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale), Fri Oct 02 2020 
00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale), Sat Oct 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale 
dell’Europa centrale), Sun Oct 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale), Mon Oct 05 
2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale), Tue Oct 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale
 dell’Europa centrale), Wed Oct 07 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)]
```

I searched online but not being very proficient in angular yet I have not found a suitable solution!
i don't understand why i get this kind of result!
you would have some suggestions?
thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must using the `momment` library :

1 : install that by this command :`npm i jalali-moment`

2 : import that : `import * as moment from 'jalali-moment';`

3 : and create a function in share Service :

```
transformDate(date: any, format = 'YYYY/MM/DD'): string {
    const MomentDate = moment(date, format);
    return MomentDate.locale('en').format(format);
}
```

4 : finally you must just use this function and pass data to that.

Comment: Do not moment.js for new projects, it's deprecated https://momentjs.com/docs/. There are other better libraries

Answer (score 1):

try

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

reservedDate: Date[];
reservedString: string[];

reservedString = reservedDate.map(d => formatDate(d, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en'));
```